# a4j:commandButton does not work as expected with JSF 2.2 and RichFaces 4.3.2, oncomplete gives malformedXML

Tags: richfaces, jboss7.x, mojarra, jsf-2.2

I am using Mojarra's implementation(2.2) of JSF spec 2.2 on JBOSS 7 with RichFaces 4.3.2. The problem that I am facing is that a4j:commandButton performs its action but the oncomplete does not work as expected and I get a malformedXML in response. 
I get the following error : event.description: "During update: javax.faces.ViewState not found"

I checked in the browser console when the HTML is rendered for the first time , the hidden tag for javax.faces.viewState is

But I have no idea why does the server sends javax.faces.viewState in response for a4j:commandButton and tries to find an element with id = javax.faces.viewState and fails. I debugged jsf.js and when it tries to match the given regex in js with the HTML element that I get in server response it fails.(because regex is  /javax.faces.ViewState:.*$/ and I get javax.faces.ViewState in response).

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/message/826331, upcoming RichFaces 5 Alpha release will be JSF 2.2 compatible

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that RichFaces 4.3.2 is not compatible yet with JSF 2.2!
Check out this URL:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/230065